# Rusting without water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

I was under the assumption that corrosion (rust specifically) required water + oxygen to occur. But the word equation below states that only oxygen is necessary. I know this is true but I do not know the explanation behind it. Could someone help me understand? Apparently water magically appears from somewhere.

A middle to high school level of explanation would be ideal, not too advanced.

metal + oxygen ->  metal oxide

metal + oxygen + water -> metal oxide

Comment: What's your question really, 'cause I don't see much sense here? Water is a often a problem if you want to get oxide - that's why rust isn't pure oxide.

Comment: Quite simply I want to know how does rusting occur without the notable presence of liquid water? I thought it was essential to rust formation. But as I stated apparently rust can form by reacting iron with only oxygen? I'd like to understand how this works if you'd be so kind?

Comment: Why, many metals would react with oxygen directly (just like they teach in middle school, metal + oxygen $\to$ metal oxide ). Iron, for one, certainly would. It may be going slower than with water, and produce different resulting compounds (because common rust is not really oxide, it is hydroxide), but anyway.

Comment: Try an experiment: Using tongs, hold a piece of steel wool in a propane torch flame. Let us know the results. Hopefully you will have answered your own question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the rust reaction was not well explained.  The following is the formula for iron rusting with water.
$$\ce{4Fe + 3O2 -> 4Fe^3+_(aq) + 6O^2- _(aq) -> 2Fe2O3}$$ 
Water will dissolve the iron because often carbon dioxide is available in the atmosphere to make the water slightly acidic. With the help of acidity electrons can be transported much easier from from dissolved iron to dissolved oxygen. Where oxygen, iron, and water meet is most often where rust pits start to form.

Without water the formula is the following:
$$\ce{4Fe + 3O2 -> 2Fe2O3}$$
This reaction is very slow.  More energy is needed to initiate the reaction as in the case with burning steel wool, or another means is needed to transport electrons.  Dirt, grime, residues, or any number of things can transport electrons resulting in rust.

Comment: Rusting is a more sophisticated reaction than what I have described. For the benefit of the person who asked the question a simple metal and oxidizing component was chosen. The real world is likely to have metallic impurities, hydroxide, a mix of iron II and iron III, condensation, coatings, and a whole host of other things specific to a particular circumstance. Going into detail is not necessary to answer the question.